# How to change the default width of the record selection field on the TYPO3 BE

Tags: typo3

When selecting a record for a FCE, CE, plugin or anything else in TYPO3, there is a somewhat narrow text area that lists your records once you have selected them from the popup. That text area is too small for the length of the names of my records.

How do I globally set the width of this field, so that for all BE users, it's a custom width that is much wider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not option to set the width of an input field of all modules and extensions globally. The reason is that every field is identified by it extension name.

Comment: Is there a way through TSConfig per user?

Comment: Could I also modify the core CSS? Or write an extension that modifies that one bit? I see it has a width set but it looks like it's done dynamically, or it's actually hard-coded in the back end code somewhere.

Comment: Maybe for a specific extension. The width of the input field is mostly coded in the tca if you can find a way to override it. I would just patch the tca or write a TSConfig.

Comment: The specific form this change is needed most-needed for happens to be in an extension already, and if I had to curtail change to just the forms generated by the extension, that would work.

Comment: I don't think there is a general approach to solve your problem except the userTSconfig.