How to change the length of a form field in TYPO3
I created a simple contact form in my website and I don’t see how I can change the lenght of the fields in my form (name, subject, mail address, question).
They all have the same length.
The TYPO3 version is 9.5.47
I expected a handle to resize the field.

one could expect to find that in the docs: Form elements and their properties, but that seems not available, as seen in this (old?) answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095402/how-to-change-the-default-width-of-the-record-selection-field-on-the-typo3-be  (P.S. But that are hints you could have found yourself....)

Is there someone who could help me?

Do Validators help ? ("Validators can be added to all form elements to check the input for "validity" - i.e. presence, meaningfulness and correctness.")

Validators wouldn't help because the problem is not the length of the input data but the visual size/length of the field. From a different source I understand I can solve the problem by changing the CSS.

You can style them by CSS, there is no need to change anything else.
